# Proving $\nabla^2(|f|^{2})=4 |\partial f / \partial z|^2$ via a "Laplacian Approach"

Tags: complex-analysis, laplacian

In the text "Function Theory of a Complex Variable", I'm having trouble proving the following relation in $(1.)$

$(1.)$

Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\text{U} \subset \mathbb{C}$, then

$$\nabla^2(|f|^{2})=4 |\partial f / \partial z|^2$$

$$\text{Lemma}$$

The following observations can be made on $(1.)$

Recall:

$$\nabla^2(|f|^{2})=4 |\partial f / \partial z|^2$$

One can observe in $(2.)$

$(2.)$

$$\nabla^2(|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)||u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|) = 4 |\partial f / \partial z|\partial f / \partial z|$$

Furthermore in $(3.)$

$(3.)$

$$\nabla^2(|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)||u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|) = 4|( \nabla(f(z)||\nabla (f(z)|$$
$$\text{Remark}$$
The formal manipulation of Partial Derivatives , used within the results of this proof can be formally notioned as follows:

$$\nabla f(a) = ( \partial f / \partial x_{i}(a),..., \partial f / \partial x_{n})$$
Finally in $(4.)$

$(4)$

$$\partial f / \partial x_{}(|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|\partial f / \partial y_{i}|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|) = 4|( \nabla(f(z)|( \nabla (f(z)|$$

$$\partial f / \partial x_{i}|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|\partial f / \partial y_{i}|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|) = 4 |\partial f / \partial x_{}(|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|\partial f / \partial y_{}|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|)$$

$$\text{Remark}$$
The recent developments are only true when our function $f(z)$, satisfies Laplace's Equation:
$$\nabla^2  \phi = 0$$

I'm initially have trouble, at this phase of the proof, it looks like $(1.)$ holds true is their an alternative approach that doesn't draw so heavily on the Laplacian Operator ?

Comment: From the following in $(2-3)$ $$\nabla^2f(|u(x,y) + iv(x,y)||u(x,y) + iv(x,y)|) = 4 |\partial f / \partial z|\partial f / \partial z|$$    The Laplacian Opeartor can be manipulated with much better precision had I used the definition: $f=u+iv$ however $(u(x,y) +iv(u(x,y) = u+iv$ so the use was appropriate for our approach.

Comment: So building on our consideration form my eluded comments earlier, we can make some more refined observations: $$\nabla^2f(|u + iv||u + iv|) = 4 |\partial f / \partial z|\partial f / \partial z|$$

$$ \nabla^2f(|u + iv||u+ iv|) = 4|( \nabla(f(z)|( \nabla (f(z))| $$ $$\partial f / \partial x_{i}(f(|u + iv|\partial f / \partial y_{i}|u + iv|) = 4 |\partial f / \partial x_{i}(f(|u + iv|\partial f / \partial y_{i}|u + iv|)|$$

Comment: The equation $\nabla |f|^2=|\partial f/\partial z|^2$ does not make sense, since $\nabla |f|^2$ is a vector and $|\partial f/\partial z|^2$ is a real scalar, no? Also, it is very difficult to follow what it is you're saying. What does $\nabla^2 f(|z|^2)$ have to do with the problem? A lot of your expressions are incorrectly parenthesized too.

Comment: $\nabla |f|^2=|\partial f/\partial z|^2$ was the original proposition given in the book.

Comment: Where in the book? Chapter, exercise. | Edit: in fact, I can't even find a book by the title "Function Theory of a Complex Variable." Is it perhaps "Function Theory of One Complex Variable" by Greene and Krantz?

Comment: "Function Theory of One Complex Variable" by Robert E. Greene and Stevan G. Kantz pg.26 Exercise 43.

Comment: The equation there is $\color{Green}{\Delta} |f|^2=4|\partial f/\partial z|^2$, **not** $\color{Red}{\nabla} |f|^2=4|\partial f/\partial z|^2$.

Comment: The following observation $\nabla^2 f(|z|^2)$ is just another way to denote the Laplacian of our function

Comment: But why are you writing $f(|z|^2)$ when you should be writing $|f(z)|^2$?

Comment: Yeah but there's other ways you can denote and define the Laplacian.

Comment: Yes, you can denote the Laplacian by $\Delta$ or $\nabla^2$, but you *cannot* denote it by $\nabla$ (which is the gradient, not the Laplacian), and you cannot denote $|f|^2$ by $f(|z|^2)$.

Comment: Is everything clear and easy to follow now @arctictern sorry for the mistakes, made some typo's when latexing this up.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on in (4).

Comment: What's not clear in $(4)$ I'm just taking the partial derivatives of $|f(z)|^2$

Comment: Why are you writing $\partial f/\partial x_i |f|\partial f/\partial y_i|f|$? What are $x_i$ and $y_i$, why not just write $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute $|\partial f/\partial z|^2$ in a couple ways:

$$ \begin{array}{lll} \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} & = & \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = & \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial (iy)} \\ \displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right|^2 & = & u_x^2+v_x^2 & = & u_y^2+v_y^2 \end{array} $$

and then compute

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \Delta|f|^2 & \displaystyle =\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)(u^2+v^2) \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(u^2+v^2)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(u^2+v^2) \\[5pt]  & \displaystyle  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2uu_x+2vv_x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2uu_y+2vv_y) \\[5pt] & = 2(u_x^2+v_x^2+uu_{xx}+vv_{xx})+2(u_y^2+v_y^2+uu_{yy}+vv_{yy}) \\[5pt] & =2(u_x^2+v_x^2+u_y^2+v_y^2)+2u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+2v(v_{xx}+v_{yy}) \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = 4\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right|^2. \end{array} $$

Comment: @Zophikel It's not interesting, it's *straightforward*. There's no cleverness involved, it's just doing what you're supposed to be doing: applying $\partial^2/\partial x^2+\partial^2/\partial y^2$ to $u^2+v^2$, and in order to take $\partial^2/\partial x^2$ of something, you need to take $\partial/\partial x$ of it twice,  and in order to apply $\partial/\partial x$ to a product of functions, you use the product rule. The only clever bit is at the end, where we recognize $u_x^2+v_x^2$ and $u_y^2+v_y^2$ are both $|\partial f/\partial z|^2$. Also don't know what you mean by "via summation."