# The laplacian of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laplacian

For a complex function $f$, we know its Laplacian is $4 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$. But now I am trying to calculate $\nabla |f|^2$. I am looking for a formula which would help me simplify my calculation. Something possibly of the form $\nabla \langle f, f \rangle = \langle \nabla f, f \rangle + \langle f, \nabla f \rangle$. Maybe there are extra terms invovling the gradient also.

Comment: Is it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338826/proving-nablaf2-4-partial-f-partial-z2-via-a-laplacian-approac?rq=1

Comment: You say "Laplacian" and write the gradient $\nabla |f|^2$. Which one is it? The Laplacian would be $\nabla^2 |f|^2$ (or $\Delta |f|^2$).