# Proving $\Delta(|f|^p)=p^2(|f|^{p-2}) |\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}|^2$ is true for any $p>0$ for a non-vanishing analytic function f in $\Omega$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, laplacian

This problem comes from "Function Theory of One Complex Variable" by Robert E. Greene and Stevan G. Kantz, p.26, exercise 44. It is a generalization of the problem before, which was answered here: [Proving ∇2(|f|2)=4|∂f/∂z|2 via a "Laplacian Approach"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338826/proving-nabla2f2-4-partial-f-partial-z2-via-a-laplacian-appro). I tried to follow the example from the above problem and extend it but I am fairly lost right now. Any explanations or partial hints would be welcome.

Comment: Can you not just apply to previous result with $f=g^{p/2}$?

Comment: I don’t see how that would work on the RHS, for example how does $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}$ change in that scenario?

Comment: The chain rule gives $ \partial_z g^{p/2} = (p/2) g^{p/2-1} \partial_z g$, so $ \vert \partial_z g^{p/2} \vert^2 = p^2/4 \vert g \vert^{p-2} \vert \partial_z g \vert^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that clears up my confusion